# Image as link in list

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to go to Google when I click on the image that is within class1. Any help would be appreciated. 
I have this in my html:

```
    <div class="one">
        <ul class="two">
            <li class="class1"><a href="www.google.com"></a></li>
            <li class="class2"><a href="www.google.com"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have this in my css:

```
    .class1 {
       background-image:url(image/url.png);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

     .class1:hover {
       background-image:url(imagehover/url.png);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: Add the `onclick="location.href='www.google.com'"` property to it

Comment: It does not react right now. When I hover over it, it changes the background and then it does not react to any clicking.

Comment: move the class from the `<li>` to the `<a>` - you need to space you the `<a>` with the link space.

Comment: Then the images disappear. It's confusing to say the least.

Comment: need to add width and height

Comment: @Bálint That's a bad solution for this problem, and something you should try to avoid altogether. You take away control from the user, by mandating the URL should open in the current tab/window.

Comment: This is what your looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/gm69n7n5/

Comment: use `display: list-item` on your `<a>`. Check my answer below

Comment: @Andrew I did like you said. It did not react to my click. I added a title just to make sure it's reacting. Title showed up, however it does not go to https://www.google.com

Comment: @Andrew it reacted on firefox however. It did not jump to a new website. It does not work on chrome though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```css
ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        height: 90px;
        width: 125px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .class1 {
       background-image:url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/company-identity/100/Google_2015_logo-128.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

     .class2 {
       background-image:url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-brand-logo-2/512/facebook-128.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div class="one">
        <ul class="two">
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com" class="class1" target="blank"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="class2" target="blank"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.

Comment: My pleasure like to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `<a>` to `display: block;` in the CSS,and enter a `&nbsp;` in the HTML (to make sure the element shows up)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<img>` element within your `.class1`, only an empty `<a>` element, which means it has zero height and width. The same is true for the parent `<li>` element. This is why you cannot see the background image.

By adding a style like `display: inline-block` for your `<a>` element, you'll be able to give it a width and height.

(Also, it would probably make more sense to target the links themselves, e.g. `.two a` and `.two a:hover`, for the toggling of the background image.)

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79bw0oj3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
  .class1 {
       background-image:url('https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/33430');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
      
    }
.class1 a{display: block}
```

```html
  <div class="one">
        <ul class="two">
            <li class="class1"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li class="class2"><a href="http://www.google.com"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: A dash appeared, however, it did not react to clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a href>` tags need content, e.g. some text or an `<img>`.
An `a` tag turns its **content** into something clickable/navigatable, but they all have no content.

Also, the link inside each `href` should start with `http://` or `https://`, otherwise your browser will try to open a page by that name on the same server that hosts your html page.

Comment: I thought I'd be able to change the background using css. That's why I wanted to use these images as icons (links).

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` **would not work** for you since your `<a>` is inside a list-item `<li>`.

So use **`display: list-item`** instead on your `<a>`:

```
.class1 a { 
   display: list-item; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31v63v6o/19/)

If you want Google to open in the same page, just use `target="_self"`, and not `target="_blank"`

```
   background-image:url(http://gallery.photo.net/photo/5911468-md.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 300px;
   display:block;
   background-size: 300px;
   background-position: center;
   width: 190px;
   height: 190px;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-indent: 100%;
   white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a native block element

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none; padding-left: 0">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
           <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150); height: 150px; width: 350px;"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```